# re-render triggered in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the life cycle of a component, if a re-render is triggered by some synchronous operation in componentDidMount(), would the user have a chance to see the first render content on browser?
e.g. If I toggle a start downloading boolean flag in componentDidMount()  through redux, which then causes the re-render because the flag is mapped to redux for the component.

-------Update Info-----

The sync operation is just changing the start downloading flag to true, and the flag is mapped to the component, where the flag is checked to determine the JSX contents in render(). In redux, right after the flag is set to true, then the downloading operation begins. When downloading is completed, redux sets the flag to false.
Consider the following lifecycle sequence:

```
render() //JSX A  
componentDidMount() // the flag is set  
render() // re-render JSX B
```

Will JSX A be displayed in the browser, regardless of how quick it is?
the action creator called in componentDidMount():

```
export const downloadArticleList = () => {
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // set start flag to true synchronously, before axios.get
            dispatch(listDownloadStart());  
            axios.get('/articles')
                .then(response => {
                //set the flag to false and update the data
                    dispatch(saveArticleList(response.data))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    dispatch(serverFail(err))
                    console.log("[downloadArticleList]] axios", err);
                })
        }
    }
```

It is a SPA, no SSR.

Comment: in your scenario, the user can not see a previous state of your component because you change some state that order component to re-render. you want to see or not?

Comment: @AlirezaYadegari I don't want them to see the first render content which is fetched previously and is now out-dated b/c it is modified in other component.

Comment: if you don't want to show the previous state, I strongly suggest you use Spin component in componentDidmount. try to set loading  = true when you start to call your method and set loading to false whenever your method is finished. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-spin

Comment: @AlirezaYadegari That is how I implement it. The question is, render() is called before I set loading to true in componentDidMount. Re-render is called after componentDidMount(). Will first render result, where loading is not true, shows old data?

Comment: you have to set loading = true in the constructor and set it to false after your work, I give you an example in answer part to see it clearly (the example is with typescript) please see that. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things:

- How long sync operation takes
- Are you doing SSR (thus there will be time dedicated for DOM rehydrating)

Generally, I'd consider this as an antipattern

Comment: Not clear, why you are supposing this is antipattern. If "start downloading flag" will trigger some async operation (e.g. *downloading something* :D), then it's ok, and it is *recommended* way to do the things in react. But in other you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As we discuss in the comment here is the example :

```
interface ExampleComponentProps {

}
interface ExampleComponentState {
    loading: boolean;
}

export class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<ExampleComponentProps, ExampleComponentState>{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = { loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //some method {}

        //after get result 
        this.setState({
            loading: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Spin spinning={this.state.loading} >
                    //Your COmponent here
                </Spin>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project is complicated, the easiest way is using

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
          // your new flag here
    })
}, 0);
```